# Java -SpringSocial: Getting Twitter data between two dates

Tags: twitter, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I am using spring social to get twitter data for particular tag say #spring. 
What I want to achieve is get all data between two dates/timestamp. eg. data between last fetch time and current time. The spring social API allows me to get data betweem two tweetIDs but I failed to find a way where in one can get data between two dates.

Please help.

Ankit Solanki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spring social twitter advanced search.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/impl/SearchParameters.html

It has two parameters since and until. These can be used to retreive based on date / time period.

Comment: Since on SearchParameters is since ID not a dated since. You can still only to an until.